# Continuity of measures on intersection of intervals

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose we have a measure $\mu$ on the real line, and $a\in\mathbb{R}$. Is it necessarily true that $$\mu((-\infty,a])=\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\mu((-\infty,a+\epsilon))?$$

This looks related to the continuity of measures, but to apply continuity of measures on a decreasing sequence of sets, we must know that at least one of the sets has finite measure. Here we don't have that assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $$\mu(X) = \left\{\begin{array}{cc} \infty & X \cap (a, \infty) \ne \emptyset \\ 0 & \text{ else } \end{array}\right.$$

This is a positive measure on $\mathbb{R}$, but the desired limit statement doesn't hold.

Answer (score 1):

Without the finiteness assumption, it need not hold. Consider

$$\mu(E) = \int_{E\cap (a,a+1)} \dfrac{1}{x-a}\,dx.$$

Then $\mu((-\infty,a+\varepsilon)) = +\infty$ for all $\varepsilon > 0$, but $\mu((-\infty,a]) = 0$.