# Continuity of measure finite on compact sets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

This is related to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/584964/continuity-of-measures-on-intersection-of-intervals).

Suppose we have a measure $\mu$ on the real line, and $a\in\mathbb{R}$. **Suppose also that $\mu$ is finite on every compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$.** Is it necessarily true that $$\mu((-\infty,a])=\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\mu((-\infty,a+\epsilon))?$$

The additional condition (in bold) rules out examples like  $$\mu(X) = \left\{\begin{array}{cc} \infty & X \cap (a, \infty) \ne \emptyset \\ 0 & \text{ else } \end{array}\right.$$ However, it still doesn't imply that $\mu((-\infty,a+\epsilon))$ is finite for some $\epsilon$, since the set is not compact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is true. Since $\mu$ is finite on compact sets, we have that $\mu([a, a + 1]) < \infty$; but it's a general fact that if $\mu(E_1) < \infty$ and $E_1 \supseteq E_2 \supseteq \dots$, then

$$\mu\left(\bigcap_{n = 1}^{\infty} E_n\right) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \mu(E_n)$$

Choose $E_n = [a, a + \frac 1 n]$ and apply this to get the desired result.